# How do I get reponse data from 400 http response in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I have set up express in the **backend** and this is the logic if the account already exists.

```
 try {
        //check if email already exists
        const existingUser = await User.findOne({ email : email });
        if (existingUser) {
            // return res.send('Already exists')
            return res.status(400).json({err: "Account with email already exists"});
        };
```

I am able to fetch data using axios for 200/201... reponses. But not for this one. IT also returns the json response to POSTMAN, but not to axios for 400 code.
I need to extract response data 
**my frontend code**!

```
   const submit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if(password !== password2){
            setErr("Passwords do not match")
        };
        const userData = { name, email, password };
        const url = "http://localhost:5000/api/users/signup";
        const res = await axios.post(url, userData);
        // NO OUTPUT
        console.log(res.data);
        console.log(res);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `try / catch`

```
  const submit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (password !== password2) {
      setErr("Passwords do not match");
    }
    const userData = { name, email, password };
    const url = "http://localhost:5000/api/users/signup";
    try {
      const res = await axios.post(url, userData);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err.response);
    }
  };
```